# Django URL routing for one app

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to return different templates for different urls (having just one app), so basically I want to return:

One template for:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/`

Another template for:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/formpage/`

I have the project urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url,include
    from django.contrib import admin
    from appone import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        #home page
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^projects/', include('appone.urls')),
        url(r'^formpage/',  include('appone.urls')),
    ]
```

And the app urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url,include
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.projs, name='proj'),
        url(r'^$', views.form_view, name='form_view')
    ]
```

I have the views and templates , that are good, but I do not understand how can I return them based on the url, because for the moment I return the first view from app urls.py, for both urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make separate view functions for both urls (`projs` and `form_view`).

Then in `projects/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^projects/', views.projs, name='proj'),
    url(r'^formpage/', views.form_view, name='form_view')
    ...
]`
```

Or, if you want to have separate `urls.py` file

`projects/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^', include('appone.urls')),
]`
```

`appone/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^projects/', views.projs, name='proj'),
    url(r'^formpage/', views.form_view, name='form_view')
]`
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and it really makes sense , I am struggling  to grasp to concept of urls routing, and I have seen that usually each app has its own url, so that is why I wanted to use the include in the project urls.py.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add dollars to the end of those regexes - `r'^projects/$'` and `r'^formpage/$'`

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the second `urls` page? You could just set your first `urls.py` as:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from appone import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^projects/', views.projs, name='proj'),
    url(r'^formpage/', views.form_view, name='form_view'),
]
```

Comment: I agree with pocket kings; unless you need to seperate them into different apps because they do different things, you should keep it simple 's'.